# Java: delete/pack method, can someone explain?

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me how this method works? I don't understand how they move in the array to delete the item index.

```
private void pack(int index) {.
    for(int i =index; i<noOfItems-1; i++)
        theItems[i]=theItems[i+1];
    noOfItems--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply shifts all elements, starting from the given index, one position up.
After that, it decreases the number of elements in the array.

For instance, calling the method with parameter 4, the value of the element with index 5 is moved to the element with index 4. The one on index 6 is moved to index 5, etc.

So, if you first had array
`45, 78, 1, 45, 234, 856, 4323, 87`, afterwards you have
`45, 78, 1, 45, 856, 4323, 87`

Answer (score 0):

They are writing the next value of the array into it and decreased the array size.

For example,

```
int a[] = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}
```

if I call `pack(2)` then the output of printing a is

```
{1,2,4,5,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how they move in the array to delete the item index.

They don't. Java arrays are of fixed size, so the code simply copies all items starting at `index` up to `noOfItems` left by one element, and then records the fact that the number of items the array holds has reduced by one.

Here is an example: let's say that you start with this ten-element array

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A B C D E F G H _ _
              ^
              |
             last item
```

Now you wish to delete the item at index 4. The algorithm would transform the array as follows:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A B C D F G H H _ _
            ^
            |
            last item
```

Note that the item at index 7 got copied, but did not get deleted. Its content does not really matter, because it's past the position of last item (i.e. `noOfItems`).

There are situations when this would be problematic - specifically, when you have large objects in the "dead" portion of the array, they may "linger" past the time when they should become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with index each value is shifted by one to the beginning of the array.

```
theItem[index] = theItem[index+1];
theItem[index+1] = theItem[index+2];
```

Because the value at index is never written to a new location, it is no longer accessible.

At the end the `noOfItems` is decremented by one because now there are one fewer elements in the array.

On the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` with `noOfItems = 6` and calling pack(4) the following would happen:

```
[1,2,3,5,5,6]
[1,2,3,5,6,6]

noOfItems = 5
```

The last `6` in the array is not gone, but since every other bit of code (I guess) is using `noOfItems` to calc the end of the array it is no longer seen.